# Is it possible to read the webpage html table data?

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently thinking for some automations to read the webpage data. So is it possible to read such below kind of table to read in to an excel from the webpage: excel should have a value as `name of condion,Operator and Expressions`.

**EDIT**

```
    >>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com/))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(https://demo.aravo.com/))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com/))
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com/))
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(demo.aravo.com))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'demo' is not defined
>>>
```

**EDIT2**

```
C:\Users>cd..

C:\>cd cd C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\>cd C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts

C:\Python27\selenv\Scripts>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from urllib import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("https://demo.aravo.com/"))
>>> tables = source.findAll('td')
>>> import csv
>>> writer = csv.writer(open('filename.csv','w'))
>>> writer.writerow(rows)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rows' is not defined
>>>
```

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Short answer: Sure it's possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Can anyone help me here to get it started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, check the library called Beautiful Soup, it will simplify the process of geting right information after you scrap the page

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://python.org'
browser.get(url)
page_source = browser.page_source
print page_source
```

Comment: I just installed python 2.7 and selenium in my PC. now trying to get write some code  for that. but i couldn't frame!

Comment: means you are asking to save page source in the local drive,right?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use urlopen from the urllib library to get the page source, followed by BeautifulSoup to parse the html

```
from urllib import urlopen

from beautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#get BeautifulSoup object
source = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))

#get list of table elements from source
tables = source.findAll('td')
```

The easiest way to save the information to use it in exel is probably to save it as a [.csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file

you can do this using the csv module

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open('filename.csv','w'))
writer.writerow(rows)
```

All these modules are documented quite well, you should be alble to fill in the blanks.

To make sure that these libraries are installed make sure you have easy_install, which can be downloaded via [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools). Once you have easy_install running type this into the shell:

```
easy_install csv
easy_install BeautifulSoup
easy_install urllib
easy_install ipython
```

then run ipython to enter the live python environment

```
ipython
```

this will open a python shell which the previous code can be tested from. I hope this helps. If you need more help with basics then search the web for python tutorials. `[scraperwiki][3]` has some good examples of web parsing in python.

Comment: I just installed selenium and python2.7 - i beleive! Shall i need to install anything or more  for that?

Comment: I am not familiar with selenium. I think urllib and csv come with most python2.7 installs. you could use pip or easy_install to get BeautifulSoup. You can test whether you have these or not in your terminal by typing 'import urllib'  etc. and seeing if there are any errors.

Comment: If not present any reference you would suggest me to install it, as I am new to this platform so seeking some suggestions or help in this context!

Comment: Thanks for your effort! the link you provided i used that to install python in my PC. and is there any way now to check if the required packages are there installed or not!

Comment: type 'python', or 'ipython', from the command line to enter the python niteractive shell, then 'import [modulename]'. if an error is returned then you do not have the package installed correctly.

Comment: See my **EDIT** , now where to go?

Comment: I think that it would be easier for you to find these solutions by browsing information already existing on the internet than through this forum. I am pleased to have been able to help you so far, but I think that you can probably make some progress on your own. good luck.